# Why does my hashing function have a different output for the same input?

Tags: android, hash, comparison, persistence

I've been writing this hash comparison function for an address book feature, and have been struggling with figuring out why it wouldn't stop comparing even though the values haven't changed.

The function in question:

```
    private boolean compareBookHash(List<String[]> entries) throws IOException {
    final String contactFilename = mContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + CONTACT_HASH_PATHNAME; // Path for previously stored byte array.
    byte[] previousHash = new byte[0];
    byte[] newHash = new byte[0];

    try {
        MessageDigest newContactHash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

        for (int i = 0; i <= entries.size() - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= entries.get(i).length - 1; j++) {
                newContactHash.update(entries.get(i)[j].getBytes()); // Piece by piece, walk through entries and compile it into a MessageDigest
                //newContactHash.update((byte) 0);
            }
        }

        newHash = newContactHash.digest(); // Convert the MessageDigest into a hashed byte array

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
        Log.e(sTag, nsae.getMessage(), nsae);
    }

    if (Files.exists(Paths.get(contactFilename))) {
        previousHash = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(contactFilename)); // Pull, should it exist, the previous byte array of entries.
    }

    if (!Arrays.equals(previousHash, newHash)) { // If the new entry hash array doesn't match up with the current one stored away ...
        if (!Files.exists(Paths.get(contactFilename))) {
            Files.createFile(Paths.get(contactFilename));
        }
        Files.write(Paths.get(contactFilename), newHash);

        Log.w(sTag, "Entries are NOT equal.");
        return false; // They're not equal; an update is required.
    } else {
        Log.w(sTag, "Entries are equal.");
        return true; // They're equal; no update required.
    }
}
```

I did some debugging, and discovered that newHash ends up with a different value every time, even though the input doesn't change; I can see that the previousHash is getting updated correctly, and is coming back for the comparison just fine, but newHash is always different. Does anyone know what could be causing this? Is it the declaration of a new MessageDigest instance ("MessageDigest newContactHash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");") that is causing this?

Comment: My guess is that you're populating `entries` incorrectly, but that code isn't shown here. A further guess: you're populating it by calling the `toString()` method on something for which that doesn't make sense, like an array.

Comment: I've found the issue; it was sending the entries over in a different order every time, which was causing it to hash differently every time. I'm working on building a comparator now to compare the list of String[] values by their name element in the sub-array before sending it.